# Memory overhead for structs with pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory

I realized there's a memory overhead in my structs when they contain a pointer. Here you have an example:

```
typedef struct {
    int num1;
    int num2;
} myStruct1;

typedef struct {
    int *p;
    int num2;
} myStruct2;

int main()
{
    printf("Sizes: int: %lu, int*: %lu, myStruct1: %lu, myStruct2: %lu\n", sizeof(int), 
        sizeof(int*), sizeof(myStruct1), sizeof(myStruct2));
    return 0;
}
```

This prints the following in my 64-bit machine:

```
Sizes: int: 4, int*: 8, myStruct1: 8, myStruct2: 16
```

Everything makes sense to me except the size of `myStruct2`, which I thought it would only be 12 instead of 16 (`sizeof(int*) + sizeof(int) = 12`).

Could anyone explain me why this is happening? 
Thank you!

(I'm pretty sure this must have been asked somewhere else, but I couldn't find it.)

Comment: 8-byte packing/alignment possibly?

Comment: could you please speify compiler setting for alignment

Comment: I don't think it's 8-byte alignment, since the size of a struct that contains exactly 3 ints is 12.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is *padding* the standard says there may be unnammed padding within a struct or at the end but not at the beginning. The draft C99 standard section `6.7.2.1` *Structure and union specifiers* paragraph *13* says:

> [...]There may be unnamed padding within a structure object, but not at its beginning.

and paragraph *15* says:

> There may be unnamed padding at the end of a structure or union.

Comment: yay, thanks! Now I'm curious: why is this happening?

Comment: @urinieto as far as I know this is always about [memory alignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) and the [data structure padding section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment#Data_structure_padding) is more relevant.